# Login to website and set User Agent using Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

im trying to scrape data from Facebook, but i have problems with login.

I'm using Html Agility Pack and I found almost working code. First im trying to login to mobile version of Facebook (it's simpler) and next scrape messages from other site (https://m.facebook.com/messages/?no_hist=1). It's working, but after login I got message "unsupported browser" and I need to set User Agent. I tried to set HttpClient DefaultRequestHeaders but when I added this to my code, then the login stops working and a message appears "Login to Facebook".

Here is my login method:

```
async private void login(string username, string password)
        {
            HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();

            hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36");

            HttpResponseMessage resultLogin = await hc.PostAsync("https://m.facebook.com/", new StringContent("login="+username+"&password="+password, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

            HttpResponseMessage resultPlaylist = await hc.GetAsync("https://m.facebook.com/messages/?no_hist=1");

            Stream stream = await resultPlaylist.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

            HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

            doc.Load(stream);

            string webContent = doc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml;

            HtmlNode[] nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div").ToArray();
            foreach (HtmlNode item in nodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.InnerHtml);
            }
        }
```

This code should find all  and show their contents in the console and it does, but i get data from Facebook Login site instead of Messenger site.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36");

Edit: Also download https://www.telerik.com/fiddler and use your browser to login and see if the fiddler shows the same.

Comment: Thank you, but still the same results

Comment: Have you tried putting a cookie handler in? Looking at the requests on facebook their are security cookies that need to be sent.

Comment: Or you could try https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/message